# Find the distribution of $Y-X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

> Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,2)$ respectively, independently of each other. Find the distribution of $Y-X$.

How do I proceed? As I am a beginner I don't know how to approach. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It can be done in several ways. Can you find the distribution function of $Y-X$, or do you know about using a change of variables, or using moment generating functions?

Comment: I don't know moment generating function but I do know change of variables as I am from pure mathematics background.

Comment: Okay, then this might not be the simplest possible way, but starting from the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, can you use a change of variables $(x,y)\to(u,v)$ such that $u=y-x$ and $v=x$ to deduce the joint distribution of $(U,V)$? From there you can find the marginal distribution of $U=Y-X$.

Comment: Then you may also know about the sum of independent normal RVs...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Comment: @StubbornAtom I know that. The integrand become some function of $u,v$ multiplied by the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: You can follow the procedure in the wikipedia link shared above. We have the well-known reproductive property of normal distribution, which says that a linear combination of independently distributed normal variables is also a normal variable. A quick proof can be done using moment generating functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you have a pure math background, I will give you more than you need to see where some of this comes from.
The hard way:

The probability density function (pdf) of the sum (or difference) of two independent random variables is the convolution of their pdf's, in the following sense:

If $p(x)$ is the pdf of $X$, $q(y)$ is the pdf of $Y$, $r(z)$ is the pdf of $Z=Y+X$ and $s(w)$ is the pdf of $W=Y-X$, then

$$r(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)q(z-x)\ dx$$
$$s(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)q(w+x)\ dx$$

The convolution of two Gaussian functions is a Gaussian.

The sum of two independent normally distributed random variables is a normally distributed random variable.

The mean $E[Y-X] = E[Y] - E[X]$

The variance $E[(X-Y)^2] - E[X-Y]^2 = (E[X^2] - E[X^2]) + (E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2)$ is the sum of the variances.

If you haven't seen this before, you can multiply them out, and note that since they are independent, their co-variance is $0$, i.e. $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = 0$

$Y-X$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $3.$

Comment: I think $\mathrm {Var} (X+Y) = \mathrm {Var} (X) +  \mathrm {Var} (Y) + \mathrm {cov} (X,Y)$.Right?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $\mathrm {cov} (X,Y) = 0$ and hence we have $\mathrm {Var} (X+Y) = \mathrm {Var} (X) +  \mathrm {Var} (Y)$. Right?

Comment: And $Var (X-Y) = Var (X) + Var(Y) $ if $Cov(X,Y) = 0$, too.

Comment: "The sum (or difference) of two independent random variables is their convolution." No. The PDF of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution of their PDFs.

Comment: @did  Thanks for the suggestion.  I will clear that up.

Comment: Please replace "frequency distribution" by the correct probability term: "PDF" or "probability density function". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: I like your answer. Quick question, should the variance be $1+2=3$ and not $5$? I think usually when people say $\sim N(0,2)$ they mean $\sim N(\mu=0, \sigma^2= 2)$

Comment: @HJ_beginner forgetting my notation.  I thought the standard notation was mean and standard deviation.  But I quick look up shows that you are right.

Comment: @DougM Okay cool thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Let $Z=Y-X$. Then the PDF of $Z$ is $$f_Z(z)=\frac{dF_Z(z)}{dz}$$ where $$F_Z(z)=\text{Pr}\left[Z=Y-X\leq z\right]=E_X\left\{\text{Pr}\left[Y\leq z + x\big|X=x\right]\right\}$$